# Issue with SharePoint 2013 Farm password change

Tags: central-administration, farm, password

I am facing issue in Farm password change in SharePoint 2013

I was trying From central administration  --> security settings --> manage accounts --> change passwords

error message is **Unable to write SPDistributedCache call usage entry**.

Comment: are your using the Farm account as the Distributed Cache Service account?

Comment: sorry for delay response, yes we are using Farm account for  Distributed Cache Service.

Comment: Well, first of all, that's not a secure way to run your services, they should have each one a dedicated active directory account... and another question: are you trying to change "Configure managed accounts" or "Configure service accounts"???

Comment: trying from Managed Accounts

Comment: I was changing farm password from Managed Accounts. please advice

Comment: still same issue after done the below mentioned steps. Please advice

Comment: your farm is running well? don't you have another error using features or  accesing sites? which services you have running?

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset your services and try again:

1. In Central Administration, click Application Management.
2. In Service Applications, click Manage Services on Server.
3. On the Services on Server page, locate the Distributed Cache service.
4. Under Action, click Stop and wait a few minutes.
5. Under Action, click Start.
6. execute the command line as admin: *`iisreset`*
7. execute the command line as admin:

   - net stop SPTraceV4;
   - net stop SPWriterV4;
   - net stop SPAdminV4;
   - net stop SPTimerV4;
   - net stop w3svc
8. Try to change the farm account password again.